# Parsing PNG image with baked data

Tags: image, go, png

I know there is an image package that exist in Golang that implements encode and decode functionality, but how can I get other data from an image?. For example I am trying to get iTXt chunks from PNG images, is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Sorry, but I think the answer is obvious - of course, you can do this. Just write your own parser and if you are a kind person, publish it at Github. If you chose Go you should be prepared that you will need to write your own wrappers, parsers, etc. as it hasn't libraries for any possible case as C++ or Java or Python. But honestly, how many languages you know that has this function built-in into standard library?

Comment: @RomanR. Yes I agree sorry I am not a senior dev so before I invest time in building something out I want to make sure that it does not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

@Khalil,

Looks like Go's PNG reader does not support ancillary chunks.
Check internals of https://golang.org/src/image/png/reader.go for line 87 and compare with https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5ChunkOrdering.